# Display only one entry of an table "Order"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I want to display only one entry of a table Order (using HAML)
Something like this:

```
-orders.each do |order|
  = pie_chart order.group(:used_by,:packeges_ordered)
end
```

I get "undefined method `group' for #Order:0x00007ff63f66f340"

When I write `= pie_chart order`, then my whole columns of this entry is displaying. But I only want to show 2/3 like used_by / packeges_ordered.

But I always get an error (Cannot group, undefined method for order etc.)
How can I limit the columns of only one entry?

When I do it for multiple order everything works fine:

```
orders.group(:title).sum(:used_by)
orders.group(:title).group_by_month(:created_at, format: "%m %Y").sum(:price)
```

Maybe it's a rails issue idk.

Thank you

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then return to this post to format your content into something more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a hash to `chartkick`, magic here is in fact that in rails using an aggregate function (like `count`, `max` etc.) on a `group`ed relation produces a hash of that maps `groupped value => result_of_function`.

If I guess the question and your data structure correctly, you want something like:

```
- orders.each do |order|
  = pie_chart order.packeges_ordered.group(:used_by).count
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put your method

```
def packeges_ordered_orders(orders)
  orders.each do |order|
    order.group(:used_by,:packeges_ordered)
  end
end
```

to `orders_helper_method.rb`

Then simply use it in your HAML view like

```
= packeges_ordered_orders(@orders)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so quick.

Comment: I get this error again: undefined method `group' for #<Order:0x00007fded48c4d20>

HAML: = pie_chart packeges_ordered_orders(@orders)
helper:   def packeges_ordered_orders(orders)
    orders.each do |order|
      render json: order.group(:used_by,:packeges_ordered)
    end
  end

Comment: You should read about undefined method for Class error. It's a common error and good described already.

Comment: when I do 
def self.packeges_ordered_orders(orders)
...
end
 I get undefined method `packeges_ordered_orders' for #<#<Class:0x00007f8041d7b888>:0x00007f8041d798d0>

Answer (score 0):

I'm try to do this now:

## helper

module UsersHelper
  def packages_ordered_orders(orders)
    orders.each do |order|
      pie_chart order.group(:usage_by_users,:packages_ordered).sum
    end
  end
end

## view

= packages_ordered_orders(@orders)

But getting this error:

undefined method `group' for order...

need help :S